# Setting up Microsoft Code for java with WSL

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, settings

I try to set the visual code settings for .csvode settings.json for wsl to the path where the wsl resides with the home folder. But I keep getting error that it does not point to a jdk. I have tried pointing to the local installation on windows as well as the place where the jdk resides on the wsl. None of which is working.

```
 $ mvn -version
 Apache Maven 3.6.3
 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 11.0.8, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-18362-microsoft", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Tested and failed settings of the wsl settings:

```
{
    "java.home": "C:\\Java\\java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10"
}
```

and

```
{
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
}
```

As well as variants where I add or remove slashes as well as bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** to open Command Platte and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**:

Turn to **Java Tooling Runtime**, JDK for Language Server will show all installed and eligible JDK for java extension, which is jdk11 or recent version. Choose the one that you've installed:

[image]

Then **reload VS Code** to make change effective.